# Mongoose select with - not removing __t field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have noticed a strange behaviour.

When I use `mongoose.select('-_id -__v -__t')` it removes the `_id` and `__v` field but not `__t`.

Is there something I am doing wrong with this function?
This happens with string and array notations.

Comment: Please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

This was a particular bug with mongoose. It has since been resolved by: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/13722